# Dynamic Title In Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

Looking for a solution to how to show All in Dashboard or sheet title. Along with the Title i am adding Country Name in the title. It works perfectly for individual selection but when all countries are selected i need to show All rather than name of all the countries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an easy fix, i had not selected **show "All" Values** from the customize filter drop down.

Answer (score 1):

The alternative that gives you the most control is to create a worksheet that displays the text you want, and position this worksheet in place of the title on the dashboard.

Same goes for filters and legends. If you don't like how the stock ones behave, make a worksheet that looks and behaves as you prefer, and use that worksheet as a substitute for the stock filter or legend.